# How to resolve ember cli problems when the issue appears to reside in a plugin from node_module?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, htmlbars

I am running into this problem when running ember scripts

`The plugin {"_parallelBabel":{"requireFile":"./node_modules/ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile/lib/require-from-worker","buildUsing":"build","params":{"templateCompilerPath":"./bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler","parallelConfig":[]}}} didn't export a Plugin instance`

What is the problem ember-cli is running into here? What would be a good strategy for debugging these type of problems?

Comment: This looks to be an issue with your Ember dependencies in some way. Could you post your `bower.json` file, your `package.json` file and the exact commands you are running when you see this? Are you using yarn or a version of npm that produces a lock file? Have you tried deleting your node_modules folder and reinstalling? All of those would be helpful in understanding where your problem may lie ...

Comment: In my package.json I add a script called nuke which does the following: `rm -rf ./node_modules && npm install` (could be yarn instead of npm install if you use yarn). I don't run it lightly, but it does help clean things up sometimes.

Comment: Have you tried: `npm cache clean && rm -rf node_modules && mkdir node_modules && touch node_modules/.metadata_never_index && npm install` ?